# Global AjaxStart and Stop event on visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery, ajax

I am new to Salesforce and I want to achieve what I used to do in html pages. I defined ajaxStart ans Stop event and want it to be called whenever Apex execute it's actionFunction using Ajax. here is my code :

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        alert("hi");
}).ajaxStop(function() {
      alert("hello");
});
```

Please help me! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The [`actionFunction`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) has some useful attributes.

**onbeforedomupdate:**

> The JavaScript invoked when the onbeforedomupdate event occurs--that
>   is, when the AJAX request has been processed, but before the browser's
>   DOM is updated.

**oncomplete:**

> The JavaScript invoked when the result of an AJAX update request
>   completes on the client.

So you can define which javascript function should be executed *before* actionFunction and *after*:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="testFunc" 
                     onbeforedomupdate="executeBefore();"
                     oncomplete="executeAfter()" />

<script>
function executeBefore(){
    ...
}

function executeAfter(){
    ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's ok but I want it to be global, I mean I write script at one place and it should work for all the request

Comment: It is impossible. You can store *before/after* function in one place but you have to add them to each actionFunction by yourself each time you create a new actionFunction.

Comment: That's sad.. Salesforce should work on this.. its not good.. Thanks btw

Comment: Btw the ode I am using fires on every Ajax request normally.. but I am not sure how apex calls Ajax so that it is restricting this function to be called

Answer (score 0):

After Wasting 2 Hours on it, I got a work around not with jquery but with Ajax component. Here is the code :

```
<apex:actionStatus id="pageStatus">
<apex:facet name="start">
    <apex:outputPanel >
        <img src="/img/loading32.gif" width="25" height="25"  style="z-index:10000;position:fixed;top:-100%; right:-100%; left:-100%; bottom:-100%;margin:auto;" />
        <apex:outputLabel value="Loading..."/>
    </apex:outputPanel>            
</apex:facet>
</apex:actionStatus>
```

Now this id 'pageStatus', you can use it any ActionFunction or CommanButton or anything where you can find status property like this :

```
   <apex:actionFunction name="saveem" action="{!saveem}" rerender="buttonpanel" status="pageStatus"/>
```

So it is not like global but this single element can work on all the functions on the page.

Comment: And that's all what you needed? Status?

Comment: Well I needed to do it by jquery but for the time being its working for me

Comment: The code which I have mentioned in my question works on every ajax event in the app so it's global but I couldnt find anything like this in apex